# How can I use PARTITION and RANK functionality through SubSonic

Tags: subsonic, rank, database-partitioning

How can I write an query or lambda expression using subsonic with the following functions which are easily done through SQL SERVER

Using PARTITION and RANK in your criteria

Here is the query which I wanted to convert through SubSonic

> SELECT * FROM 
>   (
>   SELECT H.location_id. L.item_id AS po_item, H.po_no, H.order_date, H.created_by, 
>   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY H.location_id, L.item_id ORDER BY H.location_id, L.item_id, H.order_date DESC) AS Rank
>   FROM p21_view_po_hdr H INNER JOIN p21_view_po_line L
>   ON H.po_no = L.po_no
>   ) tmp

Comment: What subsonic do is that create an sql code, from a strong type variables to avoid the errors on the developing, and make it more easy to write sql code. But if you know what you do on sql keep the sql as it is and use the direct sql command of subsonic.

Comment: I am not able to find Partition and Rank function in subsonic so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from below useful links:
[Converting SQL Rank() to LINQ, or alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873962/converting-sql-rank-to-linq-or-alternative)
and

http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/tag/ranking-functions/
In LINQ, similar result can be achieved by using the let keyword. Here’s an example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

from p in PersonOrders
//where conditions or joins with other tables to be included here
group p by p.PersonID into grp
let MaxOrderDatePerPerson = grp.Max ( g=>g.OrderDate )

from p in grp
where p.OrderDate == MaxOrderDatePerPerson
select p
```