# Implementing RANK OVER SQL Clause in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql, linq-to-objects

I need to implement the following T-SQL clause ....

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.CategoryKey ORDER BY (x.Rate * @BASE_RATE ) DESC )as Rank
```

...in C# LINQ. So far what I've come up with is something like ....

```
var rank = data.GroupBy(d => d.CategoryKey)
               .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(g => g.Rate * @BAES_RATE)
```

I *think* this would give me each rank partition ordered by rate * BASE_RATE. But what I actually need is the *individual rank* of a single row, with this being a subquery within a larger result. So really the full SQL query I'm working from is something like ....

```
SELECT 
    a.Rate,
    a.CategoryKey,
    a.ID,
    .
    .
    .
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.CategoryKey ORDER BY (x.Rate * @BASE_RATE ) DESC )as Rank
FROM data
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't need the exact [Rank](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) semantics (i.e. tied ranks).
You can use the index available with select projections

```
var rank = data.GroupBy(d => d.CategoryKey)
               .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(y => y.Rate * @BAES_RATE)              
                                 .Select((x,i) => new{g.Key, Item=x, Rank=i+1}))
```

Otherwise you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873962/converting-sql-rank-to-linq-or-alternative)

Comment: Cool thanks, I figured out the answer but this works too

Comment: @MassStrike Care to share your implementation?