# Is there a function in Entity Framework that translates to the RANK() function in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

Let's say I want to rank my customer database by country.  In SQL I would write:

```
select CountryID, CustomerCount = count(*), 
       [Rank] = RANK() over (order by count(*) desc)
from Customer
```

Now I want to write this in Entity Framework:

```
var ranks = db.Customers
  .GroupBy(c => c.CountryID)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .Select((g, index) => new {CountryID = g.Key, CustomerCount = g.Count, Rank = index+1});
```

There are two problems with this:

1. It doesn't work.  EF throws a `System.NotSupportedException`; evidently there's no SQL translation for the [overload of `.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638(v=vs.110).aspx) that uses the row number; you would have to pull everything into memory with a `.ToList()` in order to be able to call this method; and
2. Even if you run the method in local memory, it doesn't handle equal rankings the way the [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(RANK_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) function does in SQL, i.e. they should have an equal rank, and then the following item skips to the original order.

So how should I do this?

Comment: AKAIK Rank() has no builtin function in LINQ. This answer uses your approach, but it seems to work for them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21035060/7720  or this question has several options.

Comment: @Romias you set me on the trail to find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10705535/7850) which solved my problem.  Please feel free to write it up as an answer here so I can give you credit!

Comment: Glad I help you... I put the comment as an Answer! Thanks!

Comment: That's a little bizarre... why would someone have downvoted this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK Rank() has no builtin function in LINQ. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10705535/7850) uses your approach, but it seems to work for them.  Here's how you could use it:

```
var customersByCountry = db.Customers
    .GroupBy(c => c.CountryID);
    .Select(g => new { CountryID = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
var ranks = customersByCountry
    .Select(c => new 
        { 
            c.CountryID, 
            c.Count, 
            Rank = customersByCountry.Count(c2 => c2.Count > c.Count) + 1
        });
```

Comment: Thanks!  I added some code so you can see it applied.