# Linq for rank() equivalent in SQL Server -

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

How can order my list using Linq equals rank() over in SQL ?

For example rank is my `List<Player>`

```
class Player
{
    public int Id;
    public int RankNumber;
    public int Points;
    public int Name;

}
```

Original Rank list:

```
RankNumber   Points  Name    Id
    1          100    James   01
    2          80     Mike    50
    3          80     Jess    22
    4          50     Jack    11
    5          50     Paul    03  
    6          10     Monik   13
```

I need this Rank:

```
RankNumber   Points  Name    Id
    1          100    James   01
    2          80     Mike    50
    2          80     Jess    22
    4          50     Jack    11
    4          50     Paul    03  
    6          10     Monik   13
```

Comment: Seems to be a few different solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873962/converting-sql-rank-to-linq-or-alternative).

Comment: You could try this [answer1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953645/implementing-rank-over-sql-clause-in-c-sharp-linq) or this [answer2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873962/converting-sql-rank-to-linq-or-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good way to convert this directly to Linq to SQL but you could do this:

```
var rankedPlayers = players
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Points)
    .Select((p, r) => new Player
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        RankNumber = players.Where(pl => pl.Points > p.Points).Count() + 1,
        Points = p.Points,
        Name = p.Name
    });
```

It gives you the correct output but will convert horribly and inefficiently to SQL. So I would suggest this modification which materialises the data to a list before creating the ranks:

```
var rankedPlayers = players
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Points)
    .ToList() //<--- Add this
    .Select((p, r) => new Player
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        RankNumber = players.Where(pl => pl.Points > p.Points).Count() + 1,
        Points = p.Points,
        Name = p.Name
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below expression:

```
var newData = players
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Points)
             .GroupBy(x => x.Points)                 
             .SelectMany((x, index) => x.Select(y => new Player
            {
                Name = y.Name,
                Points = y.Points,
                RankNumber = index + 1,
                Id = y.Id
            }));
```

`players` contains IEnumerable of objects of type Player and `newData` contains ordered data with rank.